# Disable RestTemplate escaping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

An existing API I have to call accepts a query parameter in the form

```
?key=001|ABC|123456
```

However `RestTemplate`, using its internal `UriBuilder` is escaping the `|` character to `%7C`.
Thus the parameter results in

```
?key=001%7CABC%7C123456
```

I've tried setting a custom `UriTemplateHandler` via `setUriTemplateHandler`, using a new `DefaultUriBuilderFactory`

```
final var uriBuilder = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
```

and disabling the encoding and parsing

```
uriBuilder.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.NONE);
uriBuilder.setParsePath(false);
```

however another exception is thrown internally when constructing the `URI`

```
URI.create(url)
```

saying an illegal character is present, which is, obviously `|`.

How can I totally disable this behavior in Spring, using `RestTemplate`?
I cannot use escaped values.

Executing the same call via SoapUI, using a non-escaped URL, returns the correct response.

Comment: It will always create an URI which is a java class and has nothing to do with Spring. The `|` is an illegal char in the request and must be encoded. Even if you would put | in the URL the browser would actually encode the actual request.

Comment: @M.Deinum I know it isn't valid and that it should be escaped. However, if I escape it, the remote API doesn't behave correctly. Trying the URL un-escaped in SOAP-UI gives the correct response.

Comment: The `URI` class only allows valid URLs AFAIK (that is a regular java class and not related to Spring).

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is the `URI` class is used internally by a `UriBuilderFactory`, which is a Spring component. I'd like to avoid dealing with a raw `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Which internally uses a `URL` which I think suffers the same.

Comment: @M.Deinum did it successfully with `HttpURLConnection`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that there is no clean way to do this with Spring classes.
In the end I've choosen for the raw `HttpURLConnection`, which, while not as easy-to-use, provide all the required functionality anyway.

The thing is internally, the `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` which is the one used to build the final URI, uses the `java.net.URI` class, which obey RFCs rules.

```
private URI createUri(UriComponents uric) {
    if (encodingMode.equals(EncodingMode.URI_COMPONENT)) {
        uric = uric.encode();
    }
    return URI.create(uric.toString());
}
```

As you can see, even if you disable encoding via

```
uriBuilder.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.NONE);
```

the final result is always a call to `URI.create`.
You cannot escape that, if not by providing a custom `UriBuilderFactory`.